# Displaying a list into a Razor view

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

My goal is to combine two table and display them in a list on a razor view. With some help I was able to construct a linq query that pulls the data, as well as a viewModel.

I have the linq query here

```
public IActionResult AvailableJobIndex()
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
        
        var jobs =
           from h in _context.PostThrs
           join e in _context.PostEigs on h.ThrZero equals e.EigZero
           where h.ThrDate > today && h.ThrText == "SERVICE DATE"
              && e.EigAgen == "OPEN"
           select new AgentClientIndexVM
           {
               Zero = h.ThrZero,
               ThrDate = h.ThrDate,
               ThrTime = h.ThrTime,
               ThrText = h.ThrText,
               EigAgen = e.EigAgen,
               EigRole = e.EigRole,
               EigLoad = e.EigLoad,
               EigNote = e.EigNote
           };


        return View(jobs.ToList());
    }
```

Below is the viewmodel that I constructed.

```
public class AgentClientIndexVM
{
    public string Zero { get; set; }

    public DateTime ThrDate { get; set; }

    public string ThrTime { get; set; }

    public string ThrText { get; set; }

    public string EigAgen { get; set; }

    public string EigRole { get; set; }

    public decimal EigLoad { get; set; }

    public string EigNote { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't put together a working view. My problem comes when I try to use a foreach statement. The viewmodel doesn't carry the list over. Please advise as to how to display the list in the view. Thanks

update:

this is my view. I cut it down with "..."

```
@model AURA.ViewModels.AgentClientIndexVM 

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AvailableJobIndex";
}

<h1>Available Job Index</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zero)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ThrDate)
            </th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zero)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ThrDate)
                </td>
                ...
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="PostDetail" asp-route-zero="@item.Zero">Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

update added another vm

```
public class AvailableJobListVM
{
    public List<AgentClientIndexVM> JobList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In your Razor view, do you set the view model to List<AgentClientIndexVM> or AgentClientIndexVM?

Comment: @Lindstrøm see update with view. The direct answer is AgentClientIndexVM, but I realize that this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create another model and create a property of type `List<AgentClientIndexVM>` then you can enumerate as you are trying.

```
public class MyPageModel {
    public List<AgentClientIndexVM> MyList {get; set;}
}

MyPageModel model = new MyPageModel();
model.MyList = from h in _context.PostThrs
               join e in _context.PostEigs on h.ThrZero equals e.EigZero
               where h.ThrDate > today && h.ThrText == "SERVICE DATE" && e.EigAgen == "OPEN"
               select new AgentClientIndexVM
               {
                   Zero = h.ThrZero,
                   ThrDate = h.ThrDate,
                   ThrTime = h.ThrTime,
                   ThrText = h.ThrText,
                   EigAgen = e.EigAgen,
                   EigRole = e.EigRole,
                   EigLoad = e.EigLoad,
                   EigNote = e.EigNote
               }.ToList();

        return View(model);

@model AURA.ViewModels.MyPageModel
```

Now you can use foreach

```
foreach(var element in Model.MyList) {
    statements
}
```

Comment: Getting "AgentClientIndexVM" does not contain a definition for "ToList" ...

Comment: Exactly. You are returning a list to the Viem, but your view model is of type AgentClientIndexVM, not a list. Either create a model with a List property or change the view model to List<AgentCLientIndexVM>

Comment: no i did already added the new view model, as per your suggestion. see update. or do you want me to create an actual model...?